# Preserving CSS styling when exporting web page to Excel

Tags: asp.net, html, css, excel, export-to-excel

I'm planning on implementing a `SaveToExcel` feature in an `ASP.NET` web page by sending the HTML back to the server in a hidden field, and then just pumping it back out as an attachment with an `.xls` extension.

The problem is that the web page is heavily styled through CSS.  And since those styles aren't an intrinsic part of the HTML, I don't think they'll transfer to the Excel file.  (I now see why the programmer of the report I'm adapting this from used FONT tags so heavily, which I wondered about.)

It has occurred to me that it might be possible to run a jQuery script on the page before submitting it back to the server, copying the actual styles from the `css` property to the element's own intrinsic properties.

I don't know how well that would work, but it might be better than nothing.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carlos Aguilar Mares has a free Excel XML library that I've used in the past.  The sample code is helpful as well.

http://www.carlosag.net/tools/excelxmlwriter/

Comment: That looks like a very impressive library, and I will definitely remember it. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve my problem, which is how to transfer the (CSS stylesheet-assigned) styling of the page to the exported file. (The server-side code wouldn't know what the styles are unless I manually duplicate all the style rules as property assignments, which would be a very brittle solution.) Thank you, though!